# Getting all categories even with no products under it?

Tags: terms, categories

I am trying to get all categories which are having products but getting also the categories which are having no products.

WordPress version 4.6.1

```
wp_dropdown_categories( 
   array( 
          'class' => 'product-category-field',
          'id' => 'product-category',
          'name' => 'category',
          'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
          'selected' => get_query_var('product_cat' ), 
          'hierarchical' => 1, 
          'hide_empty' => 1, 
          'value_field' => 'slug', 
          'show_count' => 1 
      )
);
```

Even `get_terms` is displaying empty categories with the below code.

```
<?php  $terms = get_terms('product_cat', array( 'parent' => 0 ));
     if( $terms ): 
     $original_query = $wp_query;
     foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ):
        ?>
        <li>
          <?php echo $term->name; ?>
          <ul>
          <?php
          $child_terms = get_terms(
              'product_cat',
               array(
                   'child_of' => $term->term_id,
                   'hide_empty' => true
               )
          );
          foreach ( $child_terms as $child_term  ) {
             $re_child_terms = get_terms(
                 'product_cat',
                 array(
                     'child_of' => $child_term->term_id,
                     'hide_empty' => true
                 )
             );
             if ( ! $re_child_terms ){
             ?>
         <li>
            <?php echo $child_term->name; ?>
        </li>
        <?php
        }
     }
     ?>
     </ul>
  </li>
<?php
endforeach;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $original_query;
?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

> Note: In both case do not want to display categories having zero
>   products.

Comment: Are you using any e-commerce plugin or this is just custom code?

Comment: @Chittaranjan yes I am using woocommerce but still it should behave as usual wordpress post for these two function and also working correctly in localhost .

Comment: @Chittaranjan for `wp_dropdown_categories()` , we can use `wc_dropdown_categories()` and it will be done, but still no success with `get_terms()` .

Comment: @Chittaranjan Solved, but searching why hide_empty was not excluding empty product categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wc_product_dropdown_categories()` will do the trick in place of `wp_dropdown_categories()` .

For get_terms part

by replacing

```
$re_child_terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', array( 'child_of' => $child_term->term_id, 'hide_empty' => true ) );
if ( ! $re_child_terms ){
```

with

```
   $re_child_terms = get_term_children( $child_term->term_id, 'product_cat' );
   if ( $child_term->count > 0 && empty( $re_child_terms ) ){
```

solved my problem.

Not sure but I think the problem with get_terms is [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/class-wp-term-query.php#L685)

```
// Make sure we show empty categories that have children.
        if ( $hierarchical && $args['hide_empty'] && is_array( $terms ) ) {
            foreach ( $terms as $k => $term ) {
                if ( ! $term->count ) {
                    $children = get_term_children( $term->term_id, $term->taxonomy );
                    if ( is_array( $children ) ) {
                        foreach ( $children as $child_id ) {
                            $child = get_term( $child_id, $term->taxonomy );
                            if ( $child->count ) {
                                continue 2;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // It really is empty.
                    unset( $terms[ $k ] );
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to list all the categories, even if they do not have any post associated with those.

You just need to set following property to false in **wp_dropdown_categories**. method.

```
'hide_empty' => 0,
'hide_if_empty' => 1
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: 'hide_empty' => 0 will allow categories with no products, what I am getting, I want to exclude categories having no products in both the cases, please read the note .

Comment: Try the updated code, might be it will work.

Comment: 'hide_if_empty'
(bool) True to skip generating markup if no categories are found. Default false (create select element even if no categories are found).  how it will restrict categories having zero products ??

Comment: Any way, I still tried your suggestion , but did not helped . :(

Comment: I am sure, It's kind of conflict or other problem. I have checked on fresh installation, and it works flawlessly.

Comment: just deactivated all plugins and getting no better result in mine, thank you for your effort .now only woocommerce and a default theme is installed :(

Comment: Check my answer for `wp_dropdown_categories()` part we can use `wc_dropdown_categories()` . :D :D :D

Comment: Solved ! check my answer, but searching why hide_empty was not excluding empty categories.